# CLRS:33.1-4:Show how to determine in O(n*n*lg n) time whether any three points in a set of n points are colinear?

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I am going through CLRS book of Algorithms for Computational Geometry. In exercise of 33.1-4 it has asked us to "Show how to determine in `O(n*n*lg n)` time whether any three points in a set of n points are colinear?" This can be easily done in `O(n*n*n)` time complexity by taking three point at a time and doing cross product, but I am not able to understand how I can do it in `O(n*n*lg n)` time. Need help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let `slope(P, Q)`, for any two points `P` and `Q`, be the slope of the line passing through `P` and `Q`. Now, three points, say `P`, `Q` and `R`, are collinear iff `slope(P,Q) = slope(P,R)`.  Thus, fixing `P`, you can determine in `O(n*log n)` time if there are two other points `Q` and `R` such that `PQR` is a line. This is easily done by compute `slope(P,Q)` for all other points `Q` in your set of `n` points, and checking if there are any repetitions - use a set-like structure or just sort and check for duplicates. Now, iterate over all choices for `P`, giving you a runtime of `O(n*n*log n)`.

Comment: @n.m. What did I miss?

Comment: Can also be done in O(n^2) *with high probability* using a hash-based data structure.